# Latest React native project doesn't build in android

Tags: android, react-native

react-native version "0.60.3" is not working for me. The older version (eg: 0.57.8) works however. How can I make it work?

```
D:\Apps\test>react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using
 "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 856 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
10 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 7 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
-5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
-5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
-5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
-5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
-5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
-5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
-5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
-5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed
  This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
does.


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development envi
ronment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.htm
l#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8
081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > 8 exceptions were raised by workers:
  >     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
  >   -5326820-windows Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
  >     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
  >   does.
  >     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
  >   -5326820-windows Daemon #2: Daemon startup failed
  >     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
  >   does.
  >     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
  >   -5326820-windows Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
  >     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
  >   does.
  >     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
  >   -5326820-windows Daemon #3: Daemon startup failed
  >     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
  >   does.
  >     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
  >   -5326820-windows Daemon #4: Daemon startup failed
  >     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
  >   does.
  >     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
  >   -5326820-windows Daemon #5: Daemon startup failed
  >     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
  >   does.
  >     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
  >   -5326820-windows Daemon #6: Daemon startup failed
  >     This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it
  >   does.
  >     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2InternalException: AAPT2 aapt2-3.4.1
  >   -5326820-windows Daemon #7: Daemon startup failed

Answer (score 0):

Same case are Occur for me. but if you are using..

`react-native run-android --no-jetifier.`

In place of `react-native run-android` it will work properly

Answer (score 0):

I've just built from the latest and received no errors, as below:

`react-native init NewProject`

`npx react-native run-android`

This didn't start my metro builder, so in another terminal -

`react-native start`

Then:

`npx react-native run-android`

Environment:

Node : v10.2.1
NPM/NPX: v6.9.0
Mac OSx

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "testproj",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.54.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.6"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: well yeah, but the issue is for people who have 0.59.x versions and who need to upgrade. if you create a new 0.60.x project ofc there will be no issue...

Comment: Sorry, where does it state upgrade? The OP stated they had tried 2 versions, one worked, one didn't.

Comment: New project? Latest release?